flutter bottom navigation disappear when push to other page from a button
so i just made a bottom navigation bar. the problem is my bottom navbar is gone when i push to other page like the whole page is replaced.
i've searching any tutorial mostly just showing how to make the bottom navbar but not showing until if we have a button inside "root pages of navigation". (check home_page.dart)
or after inside the bottomnav pages, i shouldnt use the Navigator.push again ?
i'm aware there is a package persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2, but is this the only way ?
i also made other project with basic navbar using plain setstate, but same result.
is there anything i missed or using the package is the only way ? thank you.
class MainWrapperController extends GetxController {
  final Rx<int> _selectedIndex = 0.obs;

  int get selectedIndex => _selectedIndex.value;

  void setSelectedIndex(int index) => _selectedIndex.value = index;

  List<NavigationItemModel> navItemModels = [
    NavigationItemModel(
      navigatorKey: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
      title: "Home",
      icon: Icons.home,
      page: const HomePage(),
    ),
    NavigationItemModel(
      navigatorKey: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
      title: "Report",
      icon: Icons.equalizer,
      page: const ReportMenuPage(),
    ),
    NavigationItemModel(
      navigatorKey: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
      title: "Profile",
      icon: Icons.person,
      page: const ProfilePage(),
    ),
  ];
}

main_wrapper.dart
class MainWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainWrapper({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainWrapper> createState() => _MainWrapperState();
}

class _MainWrapperState extends State<MainWrapper> {
  var mainWrapperController = Get.find<MainWrapperController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var navPages = mainWrapperController.navItemModels
        .map(
          (item) => Navigator(
            key: item.navigatorKey,
            onGenerateRoute: (setting) {
              return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => item.page);
            },
          ),
        )
        .toList();

    var navItems = mainWrapperController.navItemModels
        .map((item) =>
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(item.icon), label: item.title))
        .toList();

    return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (state) {},
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Obx(
          () => IndexedStack(
            index: mainWrapperController.selectedIndex,
            children: navPages,
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Obx(
          () => BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            selectedFontSize: 0,
            unselectedFontSize: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            selectedItemColor: ColorConstant.selectedIcon,
            showSelectedLabels: false,
            showUnselectedLabels: false,
            items: navItems,
            iconSize: 36,
            onTap: (index) => mainWrapperController.setSelectedIndex(index),
            currentIndex: mainWrapperController.selectedIndex,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

home_page.dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: ColorConstant.background,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            // here when i push, the whole page is changed not persisting bottom navbar
            SimpleButtonWidget(
              onPressed: () => Get.to(const NextPage()),
              text: 'Click Me',
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}

next_page.dart
class NextPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const NextPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Text("HELLO FROM NEXT PAGE");
  }
}

expecting the bottom navbar not disappear when navigating from inside the "root pages of navigation" (see home_page.dart).

so i found the problem, its was navigation route error.
i convert the onGenerateRoute in main using go_router and preserve getx as state management.
please take note, this gonna break the navigation using Navigator and Get.
At least getx snackbar still working this way.
as long you manage the go_router right inside ShellBranch Route, the bottom navigation will persist.
main.dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      routeInformationProvider: goRouter.routeInformationProvider,
      routerDelegate: goRouter.routerDelegate,
      routeInformationParser: goRouter.routeInformationParser,
      backButtonDispatcher: goRouter.backButtonDispatcher,
      smartManagement: SmartManagement.full,
    );

    // return MaterialApp.router(
    //   title: 'Flutter Demo',
    //   routerConfig: goRouter,
    // );
  }
}

routes.dart
// final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
// final _shellHomeKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'home');
// final _shellProfileKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'profile');

final _rootNavigatorKey = Get.key;
final _shellHomeKey = Get.nestedKey(1);
final _shellProfileKey = Get.nestedKey(2);

final goRouter = GoRouter(
  debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  initialLocation: "/login",
  routes: [
    // other route outside shell
    GoRoute(
      path: "/login",
      builder: (context, state) => const LoginPage(),
    ),

    // shell routes
    StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state,
          StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell) {
        return BottomNavbarWidget(navigationShell);
      },
      branches: [
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellHomeKey,
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: "/home",
              pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                  MaterialPage(key: state.pageKey, child: const HomePage()),
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: "nested_home",
                  builder: (context, state) => const NestedHome(),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellProfileKey,
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: "/profile",
              pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                  MaterialPage(key: state.pageKey, child: const ProfilePage()),
              routes: [],
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  ],
  // errorBuilder: (context, state) => ErrorPage(state.error),
);

you will be directed to bottom navbar with its root screen when heading to homepage screen.

login_page.dart
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          style: const ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: WidgetStatePropertyAll(Colors.blue),
          ),
          child: const Text("Login"),
          onPressed: () {
            context.go("/home"); // can go
            //Get.toNamed("/home"); // crashed
            //Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/home"); // crashed
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


you are implementing it wrong
try this example
class Home extends StatefulWidget {

   @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBarTheme(
      data: NavigationBarThemeData(
        labelTextStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<TextStyle>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) =>
              states.contains(MaterialState.selected)
                  ? const TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFBA172F),
                    )
                  : const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      child: NavigationBar(
        height: 60,
        onDestinationSelected: (value) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = value;
          });
        },
        selectedIndex: currentIndex,
        indicatorColor: const Color.fromARGB(30, 255, 82, 82),
        destinations: [
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home_outlined,
              color: currentIndex == 0 ? const Color(0xFFBA172F) : null,
            ),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.grid_view_outlined,
                color: currentIndex == 1 ? const Color(0xFFBA172F) : null,
              ),
              label: 'Categories'),
          NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.whatshot_outlined,
                color: currentIndex == 2 ? const Color(0xFFBA172F) : null,
              ),
              tooltip: 'Sizzling Hot Offers',
              label: 'Trending'),
          NavigationDestination(
              //show badge only when something is selected //here temporary some bool used.
              icon: isWideScreen(context)
                  ? Icon(
                      Icons.favorite,
                      color: currentIndex == 3
                          ? const Color(0xFFBA172F)
                          : null,
                    )
                  : Badge(
                      backgroundColor:
                          const Color.fromARGB(255, 238, 255, 55),
                      label: const Text(
                        ' 1 ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFFBA172F),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite,
                        color: currentIndex == 3
                            ? const Color(0xFFBA172F)
                            : null,
                      ),
                    ),
              label: 'Favorites'),
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              color: currentIndex == 4 ? Colors.red : null,
            ),
            label: 'Account',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    body: <Widget>[
     const Screen0(),
      const Screen1(),
      const Screen2(),
      const Screen3(),
      const Screen4(),
    ][currentIndex],
  ),
);

}
}

try putting button for navigating to NextPage() inside screen0 see if your bottom nav gone or not, i cant run your code its deprecated
